# Save help output to a text file

Tags: r

How can i save the help output file into a txt file?

```
write(help(reshape),file="/home/debian/test")
```

does not work.

Comment: Perhaps something like this will help:  `cp /usr/lib64/R/library/stats/html/reshape.html /home/debian/test`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excavated and adapted from the guts of `utils:::print.help_files_with_topic`:

```
file <- help("reshape")
pkgname <- basename(dirname(dirname(file)))
temp <- tools::Rd2txt(utils:::.getHelpFile(file), out = tempfile("Rtxt"), 
                  package = pkgname)
file.copy(temp,"~/test.txt")
```