# How do I store the html or text of a R helpfile into a variable

Tags: r

I would like to store the helpfile of my R function into a variable. I would prefer to store the html version. I would like to do this so that I can write it into a local `.html` file.

For example, `help(glm)` generates the following text in the `Help` pane of Rstudio:

```
glm {stats} R Documentation
Fitting Generalized Linear Models
Description

glm is used to fit generalized linear models, specified by giving a symbolic description of the linear predictor and a description of the error distribution.
Usage
...
```

and the corresponding html version, with markdown, can be found at: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/glm.html

However, I have not found anyway of storing a copy of this html as a variable. I have tried `helptext <- help(glm)`, which gives

```
> str(helptext)
Class 'help_files_with_topic'  atomic [1:1] /usr/lib/R/library/stats/help/glm
  ..- attr(*, "call")= language help(topic = glm)
  ..- attr(*, "topic")= chr "glm"
  ..- attr(*, "tried_all_packages")= logi FALSE
  ..- attr(*, "type")= chr "html"
```

Comment: May be this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035254/save-help-output-to-a-text-file

Comment: Great, thanks, simply use `Rd2HTML` instead of `Rd2txt` to get a html

Comment: Happy for this to be closed as a duplicate. I have also posted the answer with Rd2HTML here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the link posted by @Akrun, I realised a simple modification to the existing answer would generate a html file, by changing `Rd2txt` to `Rd2HTML`.

```
file <- help("glm")
pkgname <- basename(dirname(dirname(file)))
temp <- tools::Rd2HTML(utils:::.getHelpFile(file), out = tempfile("Rtxt"), 
                  package = pkgname)
file.copy(temp,"~/test.html")
```